Non-column output of `ls` piped to `sed`
As far as I know, command sed precesses its input line by line. Thus, the following command successfully outputs only the directories in the current directory:
$ ls -p -1 | sed -n '/\/$/p'

Here option -1 to ls makes its output appear in a column, so sed can process it line by line. However, if I remove option -1 this command still works. Why? Without option -1 the output of ls is not a set of separated lines.

Try "ls | cat" on your system.

Incidentally, if you want to list only the directories in the current directory, you can get the shell to do the work for you instead of post-processing ls’s output: printf '%s\n' */.
